# Weak Convergence in $\ell_1$

Tags: functional-analysis

How Can I show that any weakly convergent sequence in $\ell_1$ is strongly convergent??$\ell_1$ is the sequence space with usual $1$ norm.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540458/ell1-schur-property

Comment: Thank you..But how the mathematical symbols to be written??Is there any keyboard or something else.....I'm a new user of this site.That's why I do not know much about it

Comment: @Irfan See this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/588038).

Comment: Okay..Thank you for your suggestion..