# $l_1$ has no infinite dimensional subspace that is reflexive.

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-topology

How to show that $l_1$ does not contain an infinite dimensional subspace that is reflexive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Schur's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208898/schurs-theorem-in-ell1-weak-convergence-of-x-n-is-the-same-as-convergenc) and [Eberlein-Smulian Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eberlein%E2%80%93%C5%A0mulian_theorem). Suppose that $Y \le \ell_1$ is a subspace, and let $B_Y$ be the closed unit ball of $Y$, i.e. $B_X \cap Y$. Then
\begin{align*}
Y \text{ is reflexive} &\iff B_Y \text{ is weakly compact} \\
&\iff B_Y \text{ is sequentially weakly compact} &\text{(Eberlein-Smulian)} \\
&\iff B_Y \text{ is (sequentially) norm compact} &\text{(Schur)} \\
&\iff Y \text{ is finite-dimensional}.
\end{align*}