# Weak convergence in lp

Tags: functional-analysis

Let 1 < p < ∞. Prove that a sequence
$x^{(n)}_n⊂ l^p$ is weak convergent to $x ∈ l^p$ if and only if $x^{(n)}_n$
is bounded and pointwise convergent, i.e. $supn∈N ||x^{(n)}||_p< ∞ \;and \;x^{(n)}_k n→∞ −−−−→ x_k$for
every k ∈ N. Is this equivalence still true for p = 1 or p = ∞????
Do we start with letting X be a general Banach space and X∗ its dual?? Do we assume xn weakly converges to x and also x is bounded? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Working in general Banach spaces won't help; this property is special to $\ell^p$ spaces.  (The concept of "pointwise convergent" doesn't even make sense in a general Banach space.)  However, you will want to remember some general Banach space facts, like the uniform boundedness principle.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "$x$ is bounded".  But for instance, it should be clear that any $x \in \ell^p$ is bounded as a sequence of real (or complex) numbers, i.e. $\sup_k |x_k| < \infty$, simply because $|x_k| \le \|x\|_p$ for every $k$.

Comment: What about if p is 1 or inf how and why doe it change the weak convergeants

Comment: In $\ell^1$, for sequences, weak convergence is equivalent to convergence in norm; this is [Schur's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208898/schurs-theorem-in-ell1-weak-convergence-of-x-n-is-the-same-as-convergenc?noredirect=1&lq=1).  In $\ell^\infty$ things are more difficult because [the dual $(\ell^\infty)^*$ is complicated to describe](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868787/dual-of-l-infty-is-not-l1).

Comment: But for quick counterexamples: in $\ell^1$, let $x^{(n)}_k = \delta_{n,k}$, i.e. $x^{(n)}$ has 1 as its $n$th element and 0 everywhere else.  Every $x^{(n)}$ has norm 1, and $x^{(n)}_k \to 0$ for every $k$, so the sequence converges pointwise to 0.  However the linear functional $f(x) = \sum_k x_k$ is continuous and satisfies $f(x^{(n)})=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: In $\ell^\infty$, let $x^{(n)}_k = 1$ for all $k \ge n$ and 0 otherwise.  This converges pointwise to 0 and has constant norm 1.  Consider the closed subspace $C$ of $\ell^\infty$ consisting of sequences $x$ for which $\lim_{k \to \infty} x_k$ exists, and consider the continuous linear functional $f_0$ on $C$ defined by $f(x) = \lim_{k \to \infty} x_k$.  Note $x^{(n)} \in C$ and $f_0(x^{(n)}) = 1$ for all $n$.  Use Hahn-Banach to extend $f_0$ to a continuous linear functional $f$ on $\ell^\infty$.  Then we still have $f(x^{(n)}) = 1$ for every $n$.