# Weak convergence in $\ell^1$ implies strong convergence in $\ell^1$. Understanding proof.

Tags: functional-analysis

See the suggested proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2208938/253944). The thing I don't understand is that the functional $f\in(\ell^1)^*$, corresponding to a sequence $y\in\ell^\infty$ depends on the index $j$ in its definition. So let $f_j$. Then David Bowman shows that $(|f_j(x^{N_j})|)_{j=1}^{\infty}$ is strictly bounded away from zero for each $j\in\mathbb{N}$. Why does this contradict that $(x^{N_j})_{j=1}^{\infty}$ convergence weakly to $0$?

Edit: It looks like I just misread the definition. It *does not* depend on $j$.

Comment: If $(x^{N_j})_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges weakly to $0$ in $\ell^1$, then $f(x^{N_j})$ converges to $f(0) = 0$ for every $f\in(\ell^1)^\ast$ by definition of weak convergence. Does this help?

Comment: The issue was resolved when I realized that $f$ indeed is not dependent on $j$.