# Prove that if any sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset l^p$ which converges weakly to $0 \in l^p$ converges in norm to $0$, then $p=1$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $1\leq p < \infty$. Prove that if any sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset l^p$ which converges weakly to $0 \in l^p$ converges in norm to $0$, then $p=1$.

I started with assuming that $p>1$ then I found a sequence $(e_n)_n$ the standard basis in $l^p$ for which this isnt true. ($e_n \to 0$ (weak) but the norm is $1$).

Can someone help me with the case $p=1$?

Comment: The case $p=1$ is trivial. What you have to show is that $p=1$, and this is fulfilled.

Comment: How is the case $p=1$ trivial? @PhoemueX

Comment: Your task is the following: "Assume XYZ, then show $p=1$." But in the case $p=1$, it is trivial that $p=1$.

Comment: Yes, but I need help showing that it is fufilled when p=1. @PhoemueX

Comment: This is not what you stated as your task, but see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42609/strong-and-weak-convergence-in-ell1. EDIT: Clarification: Your task (as you posted it) does NOT say that you need to show that XYZ holds if $p=1$. It just says that you need to show that XYZ can only ever be true if $p=1$.

Comment: Yes, that is why I started with $p>1$ To show that it couldnt be true. Why cant I then assume p=1 and then show that it is in fact true? @PhoemueX

Comment: This is what you want to do, and I think that you will find PhoemueX's link helpful. Some might find it unclear from your post that you already showed the property does not hold whenever p>1.