# If $X$ is reflexive and $A \in \mathcal{L}(c_0,X)$ then show that $A$ is a compact operator.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, compactness, compact-operators

**Exercise :**

> Let $X$ be a reflexive Banach space and $A \in \mathcal{L}(c_0,X)$. Show that $A$ is a compact operator.

**Thoughts :**

First of all, I know that if $X,Y$ are Banach then $A \in \mathcal{L}_c(X,Y)$ **iff** $A^* \in \mathcal{L}_c(X,Y)$. In our case, $c_0$ is a banach space (when equipped with the sup-norm). So essentialy it may come down to proving such a statement.

If the adjoint operator $A^* : X^* \to c^*_0$ is considered, then I know that $c_0^* \simeq \ell_1$ and that $X^*$ should be reflexive too, but I seem to struggle using sequential statements to work a proof.

Also, this is part of exercises on our notes after being introduced to Spectral Theory, so there may be a solution involving that, despite not having found anything that may help (as most Lemmas involve a Bounded Linear Functional from a space to itself).

Any hints or elaborations will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what is this, your homework?

Comment: @uniquesolution Self study exercises on our topics from notes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> An operator $T$ from a Banach space $X$ to a Banach space $Y$ is compact if      and only if for every bounded sequence $x_n$ in $X$, there is a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ such that $Tx_{n_k}$ converges in $Y$ (in the norm).

Consider the adjoint operator $A^*:X^*\to (c_0)^*\simeq\ell_1$. Let $(x_n^*)$ be a bounded sequence in $X^*$. Since $X$ is reflexive, so is $X^*$. Every bounded sequence in a reflexive Banach space has a weakly convergent subsequence, so there exists a subsequence $(x_{n_k}^*)$ converging weakly.
Since $A^*$ is continuous, it is also weakly continuous, that is, $A^*x_{n_k}^*$ converges weakly to some element $y\in\ell_1$. But in $\ell_1$ weak convergence is equivalent to norm-convergence. Therefore $A^*x_{n_k}^*$ converges in norm. We have thus verified that the condition above holds, so $A^*$ is compact, and so is $A$.

**Added in response to some requests for clarification.**

The argument above relies on some classical theorems in Banach space theory, which apparently are not sufficiently well known.

The first theorem is that *in a reflexive Banach space every bounded sequence has a weakly convergent subsequence*. For a proof, see [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi9tbCc0-XgAhWFa1AKHbkdCucQFjABegQIBRAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmathonline.wikidot.com%2Fevery-bounded-sequence-in-a-reflexive-space-has-a-weak-conve&usg=AOvVaw1AvMEGxy02bpIKsu7kbAtD).

The second theorem is that *in $\ell_1$ the weak and norm-topologies are equivalent.* In particular, weak convergence of sequences is equivalent to norm convergence of sequences. Most textbooks on Banach spaces contain this theorem. For several references, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42609/strong-and-weak-convergence-in-ell1).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy - See my edited post which answers your question and explains why we **can** say that in $\ell_1$ weak convergence implies norm convergence.

Comment: @Rebellos. I do not wish to offend you but judging by your posts on Banach spaces you need to do a lot of reading before you can follow standard arguments in Banach space theory.

Comment: @Rebellos I understand your academic limitations. It is my modest opinion that problems mentioning the space $c_0$, and "reflexive Banach space" do not require the tools of Operator Theory, but rather, the tools of classical Banach spaces theory, some samples of which appear in my post. I doubt that the exercises you brought recently in several posts are part of an Operator Theory course. I strongly advise you to read an introductory text on Banach space theory. A friendly text is "A short course in Banach space theory", by N.L. Carothers (2004).

Comment: @Rebellos I see. Then I would be extremely interested to see what kind of solutions to these exercises are proposed by your instructors, that use Spectral theory etc.

Comment: @Rebellos - Could you kindly mention here the recommended textbook(s) for your Operator Theory course?

Comment: @Rebellos. Thanks for explaining. Where do you go to university?

Comment: @uniquesolution Your answer is neat. I forgot that in reflexive spaces balls are weakly sequentially compact. Sorry for creating confusion.