# Weak and strong convergence in the sequence space $\ell^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Consider the sequence space $\ell^p=L^p(\mathbb N)$, where $1\leq p \leq \infty$. Let $\mathbf x_n=(x^n_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ be a sequence in $\ell^p$, such that  $\mathbf x_n\overset{w}{\to} \mathbf x$. The question is: what **additional** condition are required to imply that $\mathbf x_n$ converges to $\mathbf x$ in norm?

The case $p=1$ does not require any additional conditions, as answered [here,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42609/strong-and-weak-convergence-in-ell1) but for $1<p<\infty$, the sequence $\mathbf e_n=(0,0,\ldots,0,1,0,,0\ldots)$ is $w$-convergent but not convergent in norm.

So, is there a nice sufficient condition for $\mathbf x_n$ to be convergent in norm, expressed in terms of, for example, a bound?

Comment: A very strong condition is that there be an $x$ in $\ell^p$ with $|x^{(n)}|≥ |x_k^{(n)}|$ for all $n,k$, ie an $x$ that dominates the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The additional condition is 
$$\tag{*}
\lim_{K\to +\infty}\sup_{n\geqslant 1}\sum_{k\geqslant K}\lvert x_{k}^n-x^n\rvert^p=0. 
$$
Indeed, write 
$$
\sum_{k\geqslant 1}\left\lvert x_{k}^n-x_n\right\rvert^p=\sum_{k=1}^{K-1}\left\lvert x_{k}^n-x_n\right\rvert^p+\sum_{k\geqslant K}\left\lvert x_{k}^n-x_n\right\rvert^p\leqslant 
\sum_{k=1}^{K-1}\left\lvert x_{k}^n-x_n\right\rvert^p+\sup_{N\geqslant 1}\sum_{k\geqslant K}\left\lvert x_{k}^N-x^N\right\rvert^p.
$$
Using the weak convergence, we derive that for all fixed $K$, $\sum_{k=1}^{K-1}\left\lvert x_{k}^n-x_n\right\rvert^p\to 0$ hence 
$$
\limsup_{n\to \infty}\lVert x_n-x\rVert_p\leqslant \sup_{N\geqslant 1}\sum_{k\geqslant K}\left\lvert x_{k}^N-x^N\right\rvert^p.
$$