# What is the meaning of this symbol $\langle x,y^{(k_j)}\rangle ?$

Tags: functional-analysis

In this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/42620/557708) It is written that

> a subsequence $\left\{y^{(k_j)}\right\}$ such that $\langle x,y^{(k_j)}\rangle >\varepsilon$

Here I'm unable to understand this  $\langle x,y^{(k_j)}\rangle $ meaning

I know that in inner-product    $\langle x,y\rangle= x_1y_1+x_2y_2$ where  $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2)$

Here Im  confused  about $\langle x,y^{(k_j)}\rangle $ meaning ?

Comment: Both $x$ and $y^{(k_j)}$ are elements of $\ell^1$, so the angle brackets are the inner product in $\ell^1$.

Comment: Ok @JackozeeHakkiuz that mean $\langle x,y^{(k_j)}\rangle =\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}x_jy^{(k_j)}$ Am i right ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: thanks @AndrewMcMillan

Comment: wouldn't it be a dual pairing. $l^1$ has no inner product.